# How do I represent the X-axis as the range of factor-type variables with the year name?

Tags: r, shiny

I want to make panel that can set the range of the x-axis like `DataRangeInput`.

However the x-values are factors so i have no idea how to set the range of factors.

```
cTempData <- read.csv("tidy_league.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    theme = "bootstrap.css",

    titlePanel("EPL Teams Performance 2009-2019"),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
            div(
                id = "form",
                selectizeInput("teams", "Teams", levels(cTempData$teams), multiple = T),
                selectInput("value", "Select the Value", choices = c("sum_goals", "sum_points"),
                            selected = "sum_goals"),
                actionButton("refresh", "Clear", class = "btn-primary"),
            )
        ),

        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("linePlot"),
           tableOutput("table")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    observeEvent(input$refresh, {
        shinyjs::reset("form")
    })

    output$linePlot <- renderPlot({
        
        if (is.null(cTempData)) return()
        cTempData %>% filter(teams %in% input$teams) %>% 
            ggplot(aes(x = Year,
                       y = .data[[input$value]],
                       color = teams, group = teams)) +
            geom_line(size = 1) + geom_point(size = 2) + theme_bw() + 
            scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2009, 2019, 1)) + 
            scale_color_manual(values = c("Arsenal"="#FF3300", "Aston Villa"="#CC3366", "Brighton"="#3399FF", 
                                          "Burnley"="#CC0066", "Chelsea"="#0000FF", "Crystal Palace"="#990066",
                                          "Everton"="#0033CC", "Fulham"="#CCCCCC", "Leicester"="#0066CC", 
                                          "Liverpool"="#FF0000", "Man City"="#99CCFF", "Man United"="#CC0000",
                                          "Newcastle"="#666666", "Southampton"="#FF3300", "Tottenham"="#000066", 
                                          "Watford"="#FFFF00", "West Brom"="#000099", "West Ham"="#993333",
                                          "Wolves"="#FFCC00"))

    })
    
    output$table = renderTable(cTempData)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could convert the factors to class `Date` with `mutate(Year = as.Date(paste0(Year,"-01-01"),format = "%Y-%m-%d")`?